# How to build Twitter-Like Messaging Feature in ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, frameworks, social-networking, stocktwits

I'm trying to add twitter-like (Check http://StockTwits.com) messaging system to add social interactivity to my Web Application I built with ASP.NET, I would like to know if there's a ready-made framework that I can use and build on, or I've to start from the scratch,

Answer (score 0):

[MonoX](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/monox.aspx) is a CMS and Social Networking Platform for ASP.NET, built on top of the Web Parts framework.